# How to include a condition to query only if has a value to Firestore Collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query to firebase where i get all products, but i need to add a condition to show products from that type only if the type is different of empty string
this is the static query that is working

```
this.recordsCollection = this.db.collection('products', ref => {
  return ref.orderBy('date_created')
  .startAfter(start_after)
  .where('type','==','electronics')
  .limit(per_p)
});
```

now this is what i tried and is not working, type_val is the variable, only include the where if is different of empty value, but i get error

```
this.recordsCollection = this.db.collection('products', ref => {
  return ref.orderBy('date_created')
  .startAfter(start_after)
  if(type_val != ""){ .where('type','==',type_val) }
  .limit(per_p)
});
```

also i tried this, and there is error

```
  ref = ref.orderBy('date_created')
  ref = ref.startAfter(start_after)
  if(type_val != ""){ ref = ref.where('type','==',type_val) }
  ref = ref.limit(per_p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let query = ref.orderBy('date_created').startAfter(start_after)
if (type_val != "") { 
  query = query.where('type','==',type_val) 
}
```

The [where](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Query) method too returns a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Query)